# How can load data from sqlite to recyclierview?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I'm making shopping cart with dbSqlite in my project. I can add and retrieve data from sqlite. And also I can add to recyclierview. But, I create a product list on recyclierview and get data from it. It should be load to recyclierview when click the cart button. How can load all data from sqlite to recyclierview without manuel adding list?

I can add data from database to recyclerview like that in CartFragment.java:

```
db = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

        Cursor rs = db.getData();
        rs.moveToFirst();

         img = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("Image"));
         title = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("Title"));
         cost = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("Cost"));
         market = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("Market"));

        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        product = new Product(title, img, cost,"asdas",market,"");
        productList.add(product);
        product = new Product(getString(R.string.dell_title), getString(R.string.dell_url), "11.990 TL","dasdaaaaas","Migros","");
        productList.add(product);
```

CartAdapter.java

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.CartViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<Product> productList;
    private TextView textMarketName, textProductName, textProductCost, textProfit;
    private ImageView imgProduct;

    public CartAdapter(Context mContext, List<Product> productList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.productList = productList;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
       View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cart_item_view, parent, false);
       return new CartViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CartViewHolder cartViewHolder, int position) {

        Glide.with(mContext).load(productList.get(position).getProductImage())
                .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.ic_glide_img).error(R.drawable.ic_glide_warning)).
                into(imgProduct);
        textProductName.setText(productList.get(position).getProductName());
        textMarketName.setText(productList.get(position).getProductMarket());
        textProductCost.setText(productList.get(position).getProductCost());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return productList.size();
    }

   class CartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
         CartViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imgProduct = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_cart_product);
            textMarketName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewCart_MarketName);
            textProductName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_cart_product_title);
            textProductCost = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_cart_product_cost);
            textProfit = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_cart_profit);
        }
    }
}
```

Product.java

```
public class Product {
    private String productName;
    private String productImage;
    private String productCost;
    private String productDescription;
    private String productMarket;
    private String productMarketImage;


    public Product(){

    }
    public Product(String productName, String productImage, String productCost, String productDescription, String productMarket, String productMarketImage) {
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productImage = productImage;
        this.productCost = productCost;
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
        this.productMarket = productMarket;
        this.productMarketImage = productMarketImage;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductImage() {
        return productImage;
    }

    public void setProductImage(String productImage) {
        this.productImage = productImage;
    }

    public String getProductCost() {
        return productCost;
    }

    public void setProductCost(String productCost) {
        this.productCost = productCost;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public String getProductMarket() {
        return productMarket;
    }

    public void setProductMarket(String productMarket) {
        this.productMarket = productMarket;
    }

    public String getProductMarketImage() {
        return productMarketImage;
    }

    public void setProductMarketImage(String productMarketImage) {
        this.productMarketImage = productMarketImage;
    }
}
```

CartFragment.java

```
public class CartFragment extends Fragment {

    private ImageView imageShare;
    List<Product> productList;
    List<Supermarket> supermarketList;
    Product product;
    Supermarket supermarket;
    DatabaseHelper db;
    String title, cost, img, market;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewCart;
    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public CartFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
        recyclerViewCart = v.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_cart);
        LinearLayoutManager verticalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerViewCart.setLayoutManager(verticalLayoutManager);
        db = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());

        Cursor rs = db.getData();
        rs.moveToFirst();

         img = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("Image"));
         title = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("Title"));
         cost = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("Cost"));
         market = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("Market"));

        productList = new ArrayList<>();
        product = new Product(title, img, cost,"asdas",market,"");
        productList.add(product);

        CartAdapter myAdapter = new CartAdapter(getActivity(), productList);
        recyclerViewCart.setAdapter(myAdapter);

}
```

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: extend [CursorRecyclerAdapter](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter instead of `RecyclerView.Adapter`

Comment: @PembaTamang I want to add cart as a list to recyclierview when I click cart button.

Answer (score 0):

Example Code to get data from SQLite DB and set to recyclerview:

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        SQLiteOpenHelper sqopenhelper = new Akdbhelper(getActivity());
        try {
            SQLiteDatabase db = sqopenhelper.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.query("CAT_AVAIL", new String[]{"CUISINE", "IMAGE"}, null, null, null, null, null);
            cuisineNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            //Move to the first record in the Cursor based on Selection Key.

            for (int i = 0; i <cursor.getCount(); i++) {
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        cuisineNames[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                        cuisineNames[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                        cuisineNames[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                        cuisineNames[i] = cursor.getString(0);
                        break;
                }

            }

            cursor.close();
            db.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            Log.v("DBE", "Error on Fetching database");
        }


        Adapter adapter = new Adapter(cuisineNames, cuisineImages);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - in your cartFragment you have to create a methode that return a Cursor and read all data stored in db, then give the cursor as parameter to your adapter .

something like :

```
private Cursor getAllProducts(){
  return db.query(TABLE_NAME, null....); 
}
```

you can ready about [query here:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query(java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String%5B%5D,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String,%2520java.lang.String))

in on createView() you call the method like : `Cursor myCursor = getAllProducts();`
then you set your adapter like this:

```
CartAdapter myAdapter = new CartAdapter(getActivity(), myCursor);
```

2 - in your CartAdapter.java class you retrieve the data from the cursor in onBindViewHolder() and set the value of the cursor to your views.

the constructor of the dapter will be somthing like this :

```
public CartAdapter(Context mContext, Cursor myCursor) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mCursor= myCursor;
    }
```

the in the method onBindViewHolder() you read the value of the cursor like this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
// move the cursor to the position of the item t be displayed
    if(!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)){
        return; //fail if return 0
    }

    img = mCursor.getString(rs.getColumnIndex("Image"));
    title = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("Title"));
    cost = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("Cost"));
    market = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex("Market"));
}
```

and :

```
@Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mCursor.getCount();
    }
```